# If I use a VPN such as IP Vanish on my office network, can they see

Tags: vpn

If I use a VPN service such as IPVanish, will my browsing history appear in office logs. My office sometimes checks on User's network activity to monitor various things. Will using a VPN service hide my activity?
On occasion they've been known to use quite a bit of data...such as user's messages sent on sites. 
Will using a VPN hide hosts visited (SSL can hide the request body, not the host itself)

Comment: Without knowing how your office has set up their IT infrastructure, we cannot answer this question.

Comment: yes, they will be able to see if they want

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is really safe, and from the sound of it, you're using a system that you don't control, to access systems the network administrator or management is trying to prevent access to. It's not in their best interest for any of these types of connections.

That being said, outside of any legal concerns that might develop (intellectual property transmission, etc) if it's your personal machine that you're using with VPN then you *should* have an encrypted channel to the IPVanish servers. That being said, since you don't control the network, you could be victim of a MITM attack if your company wanted to decrypt your traffic. There are systems such as SSL off-loaders that could be used and if you access the system via special access point or through a corporate proxy, then you could have other issues in regard to decryption. Additionally you'll want to watch out for DNS requests going through non-encrypted channels. If this is the case your company can see where you're going, they can't see what you're saying or sending.

If you're using a company computer, depending on the local laws they may be able to track everything you're doing via the use of keyloggers and snapshots of the system depending on what system is running, and whether they allow remote access and monitoring on that system.

If corporate policy is not to do this, then you're likely in violation of that policy. At any rate they will be able to see that you're connecting to a VPN over the corporate network's firewall (if they have IT who are savvy enough). Additionally they will likely feel any bandwidth the VPN connection is using, as all of your traffic will require more bits to transfer depending on the encryption level.

Comment: No I control the laptop alright. We connect over wifi. I am just using their network

Comment: If in doubt you can use a wireless network card, or tether your phone to your laptop. Otherwise you have to doublecheck all of the certs for MITM. Also they would see the initial DNS request to the VPN unless you're using a static IP for the route. If you're using internal DNS for the lookup they could replace the destination IP with a proxy server's IP.

Comment: Okay. Assuming they did not install a CA. and I don't care if they know I am using VPN. Is my data secure?

Comment: The funny thing about data is it is technically never secure. If you're worried about your company getting it, then you would need to research to see how tech savvy their IT department is... what their skill level is.